# MongoDB $geoWithin $centerSphere query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I wrote the following schema in my Node.js server:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var config = require('../../config.js');

var schema = new Schema({
        title   : { type: String, default: "generic"},
        guide   : String,
        loc     : {
            type : {type: String, default:"Point"},
            coordinates : [ ]
        },
    }
);
schema.index({"loc":"2dsphere"});
module.exports = mongoose.model(config.DATA_TYPE.SUPPORT, schema);
```

Then I wrote my dispatcher for adding, removing and research.
Adding and removing are ok but I have some problem with research.

This is my route:

```
router.route('/')
    .post(function(req, res, next){
        SupportManager.getGuides(req.body.lat, req.body.lon, function(err,data){
            if(err){
                return res.json({
                        success: false,
                        message: 756
                });
            }else{
                return res.json({
                        success: true,
                        message: 856,
                        supports: data
                });
            }
        });
    })
```

where my `SupportManager.getGuides` is the following code:

```
getGuides: function(lat,lon,callback){
        Support.find({ loc: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[ lon , lat], 10/3963.2]}}}, callback);
    },
```

The strange behaviour is that I added the following object in my db:

```
{
    "_id": "58bf2f07d5fd2a0cdde4cca9",
    "guide": "a1",
    "loc": {
        "coordinates": [
            "34",
            "22"
        ],
        "type": "Point"
    },
    "title": "tappp",
    "__v": 0
}
```

But when I do the research, using lat=22 and long=34, I receive the answer with

```
success: true,
message: 856,
supports: []
```

The array "supports" is empty.

Comment: The order should be `[lon ,lat]` in your centerSphere coordinates. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/#op._S_centerSphere

Comment: I fixed it but still not working...

Comment: Not entirely sure. Did you fix the document too ?

Comment: I clean the db and created from zero, changing also the schema and aligning all functions. I saw with adminMongo that the problem shouldbe in the query . `{ loc: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[ lon , lat], dist ]}}}`

Comment: Do you see something wrong regarding the document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is perfect! Just the coordinates value are not saved as Number.
So the Schema should become:

```
var schema = new Schema({
        title   : { type: String, default: "generic"},
        guide   : String,
        loc     : {
            type : {type: String, default:"Point"},
            coordinates : [ { Number } ]
        },
    }
);
```

And the coordinates data in DB will be now

```
"loc": {
        "coordinates": [
            34,
            22
        ],
        "type": "Point"
    },
```

while before the values were between the " " :

```
"loc": {
        "coordinates": [
            "34",
            "22"
        ],
        "type": "Point"
    },
```

Comment: I would recommend casting your then to `Number` types explicitly rather than letting the schema handle it. Explicit typing can help identify bugs later, like if you were to try and do arithmetic on the value later. Say you wanted to add onto the longitude by 5 degrees, well `"32.4532"+5` evaluated so  `"32.45325"` concatenating the number onto the end of the string rather than summing the 2. Explicitly ensuring your types can be a good way to prevent these.

Comment: A short hand for converting a string into a number type `var num = +str` use the `+` operator in front of a string, returning `Nan` if the string is not a Number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_(.2B) see "Unary Plus" for more info.